# H11 socket with D4S headlights?

Tags: headlight, hid, retrofit

I would really like to upgrade my mom's Prius headlights to projectors this Christmas.  It is a 2008 Prius with factory HIDs in reflectors.  The beam pattern is not terrible, but I think that a projector would make her much more comfortable.

The only "plug and play" Prius projectors are for H11 bulbs - and I do not want to upgrade unless I can use the Philips lights that are installed now.  Is there any sort of adapter or bracket that will let a D4S bulb to work in a projector designed for an H11?

This is the headlight I am looking at getting for her - http://www.carid.com/2008-toyota-prius-headlights/cg-ccfl-halo-headlights-313181.html (but I am getting them from eBay - I just don't want to link to eBay).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the projector design requires a specific bulb shape and type to work effectively (and legally - most countries require the beam pattern to meet regulations!)

Using a D4S in an adapter would not give you the correct pattern, so I would definitely not recommend doing it!

I did look online to see if I could find adapters, just in case someone was offering them, but can't find any.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking an adapter would but the arc at the proper focus.  But that is a bummer they do not sell them.